# JTextArea getting whole line

Tags: java, jtextarea, swing

How can I get chosen line from JTA ?

Comment: The solution you accepted is not very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not break the lines up into tokens. then if you know the line number you want, you can just access it via an array of Strings

```
public class JTALineNum extends JFrame{
 JTextArea jta = null;
 JButton button = null;

 public JTALineNum(){
  jta = new JTextArea();
  button = new JButton("Hit Me");

  button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

  add(jta, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  setSize(200,200);
  setVisible(true);
 }

 private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   String text = jta.getText();
   String[] tokens = text.split("\n");
   for(String i : tokens){
    System.out.println("Token:: " + i);
   }
  }
 }

 public static void main(String args[]){
  JTALineNum app = new JTALineNum();
  app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you can use getLineStartOffset(int line), and getLineEndOffset(int line) to substring out a particular line from the string returned from getText()

If you mean that you want to know what the user has selected (using the mouse/keyboard): 
getSelectedText() should give you that.

Comment: +1, for the more efficient solution that is taken directly from the JTextArea API.