# JTextArea indentation

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I'm having a problem with `JTextArea` (not a problem though).
I want to create my own college program, one of the function is to write down and save a list of homework each day. It's text area having the main function here, which is to type everything my lecturer said. But text area will act like Windows original notepad, which is not keeping the indentation. So my questions are:

1. How do I have a function where I press the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> key it will decrease indentation by one.
2. If number 1 is possible, then how do my program have behaviour when I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, it will have a new line with previous indentation? Just like NetBeans and other IDE.

Edited: I'm a beginner in Java, in truth, I'm making this program while studying Java in my college.

Comment: What is it that you already tried? Do you have some code?

Comment: KeyBindings > http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

Comment: Mr Paul: No I haven't try anything because I don't have a clue about how to detect the indent in JextArea itself.

Comment: Take a look at **[this](http://www.jroller.com/santhosh/entry/autoindent_for_jtextarea)** which pretty much does what you're asking

Answer (score 1):

> How do I have a function where I press the SHIFT+TAB key it will decrease indentation by one.

You need to use [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to listen for the user typing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

> If number 1 is possible, then how do my program have behavior when I press ENTER key, it will have a new line with previous indentation? Just like NetBeans and other IDE.

Use a similar piece of logic to capture the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key presses. Then, [check the previous line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3669391/474189) in the editor and count the number of tab characters preceding the text. Output a similar number at the start of the new line.

Answer (score 0):

you could use Javascript/jquery for indenting by inserting empty space of specific line. while  pressing your hot key  combination call function to insert five spaces on your cursor.

Comment: I'm curious how this is related to JTextArea, Swing and Java

Comment: Sorry guys javascript/jquery can be used with web app and not with Swing and core java.